# Correct execution order for passing a SQL data into an array for Express-passport auth

Tags: sql, node.js, express, passport.js, execution

I'm trying to pass the result of an SQL query into an array for authentication using Passport. When I try to use my code, the execution order seems to be wrong because in the logs 2 precedes 1. As a result, the log statement for `2` is empty and `userinfo` gets returned as `null` but when `1` prints, it contains the data from  my query. How can I fix the execution order so this function works correctly?

Logs:

2

1 [object Object]

Code:

```
    let userinfo = []
    await con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '"+ username +"'", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        //console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)))
        setValue(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)))
    })

    function setValue(val){
        userinfo.push(val)
        console.log(`1 ${userinfo}`)
    }
    console.log(`2 ${userinfo}`)
    return userinfo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a mix of async/await and callbacks that can make it difficult to follow the execution order.

I would recommend rewriting the code block to use either async/await **or** callbacks.

Here is a potential refactor:

```js
let userinfo = [];
// Use callback to just return the result
const result = await con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '"+ username +"'", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return result;
});
// Manipulate data outside of the callback
userinfo.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));

return userinfo;
```